# Setting cron for 5 minutes and 30 seconds

Tags: linux, cron

Hey I got crontab that runs every 5 minutes and it looks like this

```
*/5    *       *       *       *       blablalba
```

How can I get it running every 5 minutes and 30 seconds?

Comment: It is not possible to specify seconds in crontab. Anyway, you can play with `sleep` inside your script.

Comment: You probably cannot do that. Why every 5 (or every 6) minutes is not good for you? Perhaps add some `sleep` in your script...

Comment: Minimum interval is one minute in crontab.

Comment: @fedorqui adding sleep will only offset the cron but the period will stay 5min, the only way should be a custom task manager.

Comment: Deleted my answer, one of those brain-not-functioning days.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using Cron, have your script re-start itself using this as the final line:

```
echo /path/to/script | at now + 330 seconds
```

Or to be more "precise" in the timing : take into accoutn how many seconds you spend running the script and take those out of the 330 seconds (5mn and 30s) :

```
#beginning of script
seconds_at_start=$(date +%s)
....
#end of script
seconds_at_end=$(date +%s)
nb_seconds=$((330 + seconds_at_start  -  seconds_at_end))
echo /path/to/script | at now + $nb_seconds seconds
```

Note: you may want to use `bc` for the calculation part to avoid running into strange behaviour in case your version of shell can't handle arithmetics on numerical as high as those returned by `date +%s` ...

If your version of at doesn't allow "now + XX second", then you can :

```
compute the number of seconds the script ran for
compute how many seconds to sleep (  sleep N ) to reach the next minute
and then : echo /path/to/script | at now + X minute
```

Comment: have you actually tried this? which system or `at` command are you using? because at least `at` on ubuntu doesn't take seconds.

Comment: the man page for "at" on AIX says it does ... sorry if it's not true for all (maybe "second" and not "seconds" ?)

Comment: @mata: thanks for pointing this out, I edited to add a way to work around this (ie, wait for next full minute, and at now + x minute)